# main component not rendering in react routing

Tags: reactjs

I have this code where I want to render the `<Main />` component in all parts except the login and register page. I've set a window.location.pathname to detect the pathname and render nothing if it is the register or login page. But the problem is that the `<Main />` component is not rendering in any component either.

```
import './App.css';
import './index.css'
import App from './App'
import Main from './main.js'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from './dashboard.js'
import Clients from './Clients.js'
import AddClient from './clientform.js'
import EditClient from './editclient.js'
import Landing from './landing.js'
import AddDiet from './addDiet.js'
import CalendarSection from './calendar.js'
import Login from './login.js'
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import Register from './register.js'



export default function MainApp() {

  let HideHeader = window.location.pathname === '/login' || '/register' ? null : <Main />

  return (
        <Router>
           {HideHeader}     
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/register">
          <Register />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/dashboard">
        <Dashboard />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/Clients">
        <Clients />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/addClient">
          <AddClient />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/Calendar">
          <CalendarSection />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/Clients/:id">
          <EditClient />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/Clients/:id/addDiet">
          <AddDiet />
        </Route>
      </Switch>    
      </Router>
  )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Route component accepts children to be rendered when url path matches the route. Why don't you just include your `<Main />` component inside the routes you want it to be rendered? You would only need to restructure your render part. So for example:

```
    <Route exact path="/dashboard">
      <>
        <Main />
        <Dashboard />
      </>
    </Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the following line:

```
let HideHeader = window.location.pathname === '/login' || '/register' ? null : <Main />
```

The above statement will always result in `HideHeader` to be `null`.

The correct statement should be something like this:

```
let HideHeader = (window.location.pathname === '/login' || window.location.pathname === '/register') ? null : <Main />
```